# dash character in mysql MATCH

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of documents numbered by year / series, like this: `13-201` (this would be document 201 in 2013).

I want to do a `MATCH AGAINST` full text query for this table, so a user could grab a list of all docs from 2013 using a query like

```
MATCH (doc_id) AGAINST ('+13-*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

However, this returns no results. But when I slightly modify in either direction to remove the dash, these queries return results (thought not exactly what I was hoping for:

```
MATCH (doc_id) AGAINST ('+13*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
MATCH (doc_id) AGAINST ('+13-20*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Is the dash an illegal / reserved character in the match syntax? Is there a way to escape it?

Thanks

EDIT: I realize I could do this query in other ways (such as `LIKE`, but I'd like to use the match / against syntax so I can also search other columns if required, like title etc.

Comment: what is your doc_id declared type?

Comment: @Alex- the column is varchar(25)

Comment: varchar and ??? 10? 20? 200?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose the text that includes a minus into parenthesis.

```
select * from `table` WHERE 
MATCH (column) AGAINST ('+"13-201"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

If you don't, Mysql will treat a dash like an "exclude" command in boolean mode.

Answer (score 1):

Really, why not just put a regular index on the column and use:

```
WHERE doc_id LIKE '13-%'
```

Using numbers for full text search is fraught with issues.  You need to investigate which characters separate words (hyphen might be a word separator).  You need to investigate what characters can start words (numbers might not be a word started character).  You need to be conscious of the minimum word length (which is 4).

If you have a field with a six-character code, a regular index should suffice for finding documents.

Comment: I agree, and had edited my question to note that I realized this was a simpler way to handle this. But ideally I'd like the user to also be able to search document title, description, etc. and in larger data sets it was my understanding that the `LIKE` syntax was a lot slower. Thanks

Comment: `like` is slower for many types of search.  But not when the pattern starts with fixed characters.

Comment: I see, but the idea is that this is one of several fields they'd search, ideally through the same utility, so it's not *always* a fixed character beginning.